# Redux model methods

Tags: reactjs, redux, model, reducers

What if I have very common situation like.

```
 users:[
   {
     firstName:'Jack',
     lastName:'Daniels'
   }
]
```

I want to have getFullName, method, what is a proper way to do that in Redux, we all know that it's possible to make it markup. I have very complicated data structures and it's not that easy to make it in markup

Comment: have you tried `_.get();` in lodash? and then have `var getFullName = function(data){ return _.get(data, 'firstName', '')+' '+_.get(data, 'lastName', '') }`. If the key un your object exists, use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, there is no need to couple the data and the methods that act on that data. Redux stores an immutable state object without methods. You just need to find somewhere else to put those methods. In this case, I would create a `utils/people.js` that exposes all the methods that are required to work on people. You can then pass the state from redux to that method and get everything you need.

Assuming your state in Redux looks something like:

```
{ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith' }
```

You can have `utils/people.js`:

```
exports getFullName(state) {
    return `#{state.firstName} #{state.lastName}`;
}
```